# Issue attempting to run Brunch localhost with

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, npm, brunch

I have installed Brunch into my working directory as well as Coffee Script.

Installation went over fine.

When I try to run the local server with:

```
gorteks$ brunch watch --server
```

I get:

```
[Brunch]: couldn't load config.coffee. Error: Cannot find module '/Users/Me/Sites/brunch/config.coffee'
```

Any cause for this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for `config.coffee`, I am assuming you are using 0.9.0-beta1 (as of 1/25/12).  When you run `brunch -v` does it tell you that?

Did you create a new project and `cd` into that folder?

```
brunch new SomeProject
cd SomeProject
```

Now, do you see the `config.coffee` in that project folder (`ls .`)?  From this folder, can you build?

```
brunch build
```

Do you have a pathing issue, perhaps?  Can you call out the folder directly?

```
brunch watch . --server
```

or

```
brunch watch SomeProject --server
```

Just some random thoughts.